# Why did Pokerstars' traffic crash so much in the last years?

Tags: poker-history, poker-stars

For about 4 years I quit playing poker, because I realized I am not good enough for me to keep on doing, so I lost touch with poker world. Yesterday, I entered some of the poker sites I used to frequent and, to my surprise, the only site that does well is 2+2.

The thing that really surprised me is traffic in Pokerstars which was, yesterday (I cannot remember the time) at about 11000 people.

What happened in the last four years that made Stars traffic crash so much?

Comment: Increased rake and denying anonymous play?

Comment: Increased rake? The last time I checked, they were targeting mostly new recs and fish

Comment: AFAIK: The traditional rakeback formats for high volume players don't exist any more. They got replaced by a new bonus system (collecting chests), but the rewards are not on the same level.

Comment: It's true. This is what I also had seen on their site.

Comment: Stars got some really bad publicity in the last 2 years. Also maybe online poker in general has gotten less popular as everybody is getting better it becomes harder and harder to win money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of bad publicity, increased rake, denying anonymous play and the fact that fish left, because online poker got tougher.